# How can I remove all the entries from a many-to-many relation with symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am working on a project where I need to have a registry of teams and tournaments. A team can be involved in many tournaments so is a many-to-many relation.

So in symfony I have only two entities created for this many-to-many relation: Teams and RgTournaments.

[ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKiZm.png)

**My question is** how can I delete from a single query all current relations (truncate the table rg_teams_to_tournaments) using doctrine?

The only method I found is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528951/symfony2-remove-and-save-many-to-many-relations) but I would like to avoid loading all the entries in order to delete them one by one.

Comment: possible duplicate, have a look to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686888/how-to-truncate-a-table-using-doctrine-2

Comment: There is a small difference between the two posts. I'm looking for a method to truncate (or just delete all entries of) a table that is used in a many to many relation using only symfony and doctrine. Yet I find your link being very interesting. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DQL.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#delete-queries

`DELETE FROM RelatedEntity WHERE fk = :id`

or you could use QueryBuilder to build the same basic idea

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html

If you do not have an actual entity, use the ->clear() method on the collection. You find the primary entity (e.g. Team) and then do like $myTeam->tournaments->clear(); and then flush.

Comment: The only problem with this solution would be that I don't have an entity created for my join table

Comment: I guess then you want to use the `->clear()` method on the collection. You `find` the primary entity (e.g. Team) and then do like `$myTeam->tournaments->clear();` and then `flush`.

Comment: Exactly. This is what I was looking for. I was hoping for something to let me delete all the entries for all the teams (like truncate) from a single query but this solution is the best until now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I modified my answer above, if you wouldn't mind accepting.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use raw SQL if all you want to do is blitz the entire table.

Quick/dirty but effective.

```
$entityManager->getConnection()->executeQuery('delete from your_many_to_many_join_table');
```

Comment: Indeed this would do the trick. I'm trying to keep a 'clean' implementation although if I won't find a solution I'll probably use your suggestion. Thanks :)

Comment: I like that someone took the time to -1 my answer. Where's a better solution then? :)